# Conditional Scrollable Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a scrollable div that has data appended to it via Jquery. I am trying to get it to auto-scroll to the bottom only on certain conditions.

- When data is first loaded (.append) it should scroll to the bottom.
- When the div is scrolled to the bottom it should remain on the bottom of the div after each .append
- When the div is not on the bottom and after load (.append) it will not scroll.

I have found many topics on how to keep a div at the bottom every time it loads data on but I haven't found anything related to the third condition yet. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Here is what I have right now, it works great but if you are reading something at the top it forces you down, very annoying:

```
$("#chatroom").scrollTop($("#chatroom")[0].scrollHeight);
```

If I could tell where the scrollbar is it seems like I could do an if statement and prevent this from executing IF the scroll bar isn't at the bottom.

**Update #2**

I found a script that doesn't seem to be working for me XD; it works for others it seems. I am trying to get it to work right now. After testing it seems to work if you don't move the scroll bar, if you move the scroll bar then the IF never returns true and never moves to the bottom.

```
function divbottom() {
              var chatroom = document.getElementById (chatroom);
              if (chatroom.offsetHeight + chatroom.scrollTop >= chatroom.scrollHeight) {
                $("#chatroom").scrollTop($("#chatroom")[0].scrollHeight);
              }
            }
```

Comment: Good that you are trying already. Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the height, the scrollTop and the scrollHeight properties (as you said in your second update).

However, be sure to take theses values **before** adding the content:

```
var height = $("#chatroom").height(),
    scrollTop = $("#chatroom")[0].scrollTop,
    scrollHeight = $("#chatroom")[0].scrollHeight;
$("#chatroom").html($("#chatroom").html() + content);
if(height + scrollTop >= scrollHeight) {
    divbottom();
}
```

Here is a working [script at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/487RA/) that does what you want (tested on Firefox, Chromium and Opera).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on antoyo's answer... I would be careful with this line:

```
$("#chatroom").html($("#chatroom").html() + content);
```

I was doing something similar recently.  you can quickly crash your browser this way.  I suggest doing this instead:

```
$("#chatroom").append(content);
```